# Allow ftp permissions for every directory

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have a computer that I set up with Ubuntu but I don't have a monitor for it so it is a hassle when I need to change something in the file system because I have to unplug a monitor from one of my computers and plug it into my server. I have vsftpd installed on my Ubuntu Server and I have access to `/var/www/` and I can nagivate to `/etc/` but if I try to edit anything I get permission denied. Is there a way to give myself permission for every directory or is this a huge security risk?

Comment: You may want to investigate the usage of `ssh`, `sftp` and how to mount remote folders to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the files using the following command in a Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /location/of/thefile.conf
```

Replace `/location/of/thefile.conf` to the file that you want edit.